# ByPass Django Basic Auth

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-authentication, django-middleware

I am trying to bypass django basic auth as I want to use firebase auth on Frontend and I am only getting the id_token on Backend.

The Middleware is as follows:

```
class FireBaseAuth(MiddlewareMixin):

    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        modified_request = self.process_request(request)
        response = self.get_response(modified_request)
        response = self.process_response(response)
        return response

    def process_request(self, request):
        middleware = "[FireBase Auth]"
        logger.info(f"{middleware} Request path: {request.path}")
        if request.path.rstrip('/').split('/')[-1] in EXCLUDE_AUTH_ENDPOINTS:
            logger.info(
                f"{middleware} Skipping auth check for: {request.path}")
            return request

        token = request.META.get("HTTP_FB_ACCESS_TOKEN")
        if not token:
            logger.info(f"{middleware} No token found")
            return HttpResponse("Unauthorized",
                                status=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)
        # check if token is valid
        try:
            fb_user = auth.verify_id_token(token)
            if not fb_user:
                logger.info(f"{middleware} No info found against token")
                return HttpResponse("Unauthorized",
                                    status=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)
            if fb_user:
                # Fetch user Data
                fb_user = auth.get_user_by_email(fb_user['email'])
                if not fb_user.email_verified:
                    logger.info(f"{middleware} User email not verified")
                    return HttpResponse("User email not verified",
                                        status=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)

                logger.info(
                    f"{middleware} Got user[{fb_user.email}] from firebase")

                # Check if user exists in current region
                user = User.objects.filter(email=fb_user.email).first()
                # Create user if not exists
                if not user:
                    logger.info(f"{middleware} User not Found")
                    return HttpResponse("User email not Found",status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
                logger.info(f"{middleware} User Found. {user.id}")
                
                request.user = user
                setattr(request, 'user', user)
                logger.info(f"{middleware} Updated request user")
            return request

        except Exception as e:
            exec_type, exce_value, exec_traceback = sys.exc_info()
            logging.error(
                repr(traceback.format_exception(exec_type,exce_value,exec_traceback)))
            return HttpResponse(f"Unauthorized. "f"{'Token Expired' if 'expired' in str(e) else 'Invalid Token' }",status=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)
```

The settings File is as follows:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    # 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'ts.middleware.AddSecurityHeadersMiddleware',
    'ts.middleware.FireBaseAuth',
]
```

And the view goes like:

```
class GetUserAPIView(APIView):
    """
    Get user data
    """
    # authentication_classes = [JWTAuthentication]
    # permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

    def get(self, request):
        """
        Return data of user
        :param request: get request
        """
        api_name = " [GET: user/get_user_data] "
        try:
            # device_token = request.query_params.get('device_token', "")
            # device_type = request.query_params.get('device_type', "")
            user = request.user
............. and goes on
```

The issue is that I'm getting request.user an Anonymous User object and the custom headers are also missing in request.

How do I bypass the auth middlewares that do not alter the request ?

I tried rearranging middlewares but it did not work.
Also, removing auth middleware is not an option. I am using django admin as well.

Comment: Have you tried to annotate your view with your custom auth class like following? 
```
@authentication_classes([FireBaseAuth])
class GetUserAPIView(APIView):
...
```

Comment: @Luty yes! I tried this too. 
One thing I noticed is that when debugging, in rest_framework.views.py the request gets Session and BasicAuthentication objects in request.authenticators when making Request Object. Do you have any idea how do I resolve it ?

Comment: The other thing I'd try is changing your middleware to inherit the rest_framework.authentication.BaseAuthentication and implement authenticate(request).